# PHP SimpleXML limit number of shown items

Tags: php, simplexml

I use XML file to store my data and SimpleXML to retrieve it for use in my HTML.
Here is the code, I use:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('somefile.xml');
foreach ($xml as $quote) {
                $text = (string)$quote->text;
                $input_text = htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_QUOTES);
echo '<div class="itemWrapper">'.
                            '<div class="quoteHolder">'.
                                    '<p class="quote">'.$text.'</p>'.
                            '</div>'.

                            '<form class="selectionButtons">'.
                                    "<input type='hidden' value='$input_text' name='quote'>".
                                    '<input class="submitButton" type="button" value="create your design">'.
                            '</form>'.
                     '</div>';
            }
```

What I can't figure out is how to limit the number of results at each page. I saw how to do it with PHP and MySQL, but I am not using MySQL and cant find how to do it with XML parser.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Same as you do it with the database records: Get the total amount of "records" and use an offset and a number of items per page.

If you have 200 records and 10 items per page start and you're at page 2 you would show entry 10 to 20. So you have to iterate over your "records" and count them. If the count is between 10 and 20 show the record.